# Difference between "= and "- in babel-swedish

Tags: babel, hyphenation, shorthands

Is there a difference between the two shorthands `"=` and `"-` defined by `babel-swedish`? While they evidently are defined differently, I fail to find a difference in their descriptions or a case where they differ.

They are defined and in the [documentation](https://ftpmirror1.infania.net/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/swedish/swedish.pdf) described as

- `\declare@shorthand{swedish}{"=}{\hbox{-}\allowhyphens}` 'an explicit hyphen sign allowing subsequent hyphenation, for expressions such as “studiebidrag och -lån”.'
- `\declare@shorthand{swedish}{"-}{\nobreak-\bbl@allowhyphens}` 'an explicit hyphen sign, allowing hyphenation in the rest of the word, such as e. g. in “x"-axeln”'

Comment: @Mico From what I can tell this is not the case. For example, `generalsekreterare"=generalsekreterare` and `generalsekreterare"-generalsekreterare` are hyphenated identically.

Comment: I've deleted my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get clearly different hyphenation from both when compiling with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\textwidth=3mm
\begin{document}
xxx 
generalsekreterare"=generalsekreterare  

xxx
generalsekreterare"-generalsekreterare
\end{document}
```

[image]

With lualatex both hyphenate the same:

[image]

Comment: Alright! I didn't try different engines.

Comment: hyphenation across engines is "interesting" ;-)